# NgAfterViewInit not detecting changes made to class variable in NgOnInit function

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I am new to Angular and I don't fully understand how angular lifecycles work.

In my `NgOnInit()` function, I called my asynchronous data service which returns data from the http module. Then, it sets my class variable equal to the returned data.

However, my `NgAfterViewInit()` is not picking up these changes. Can anybody explain to me why and how I can fix this issue?

my Component:

```js
export class LeafletMapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  data;

  constructor(private ps: PeopleService, private NgZone: NgZone) {}

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    const res = await this.ps.httpGetData().toPromise();
    this.data = res;
    console.log(this.data); //WORKS, but why doesn't it work in the NgAfterInit function?...
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void { 
    console.log(this.data); //DOESN'T WORK (logs undefined), but doesn't this run after ngOnInit?
  }
}
```

my Service:

```js
...
export class PeopleService implements OnInit {
...
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
   httpGetData() {
       return this.http.get<any>(this.URL);
   }
}
```

**Edit**: The purpose for this component is to render a map. This component uses `NgAfterViewInit` because it renders a leaflet-map API (similar to google maps). But I also want to pass in some data into the `NgAfterViewInit` so I can render markers/pins on the map dynamically, and this data is retrieved from my service, `PeopleService`, which uses the `httpClient` module to get data.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Even though you made `ngOnInit` `async`, angular does not wait for it to resolve. It just moves on the next lifecycle hooks. You probably see that `console.log` within `ngAfterViewInit` executes before the one within `ngOnInit`

Comment: Ah I see. Do you know a way to make ```NgAfterViewInit``` run only when ```NgOnInit``` is complete?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. Why do you need that data within `ngAfterViewInit`? If you explain what you need to do, we could come up with a better solution.

Comment: This component uses ```NgAfterViewInit``` because it renders a leaflet-map API (similar to google maps). But I also want to pass in some data so I can render markers/pins on the map dynamically, and this data is retrieved from my service, ```PeopleService```, which uses the ```http``` module to get data.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to move the service call from `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit`. However, you should be able to pass data through `@Input()` into sub-components. Since you rely on `AfterViewInit`, I assume there are some other components that you used in `LeafletMapComponent`

Comment: I moved my service call to ```NgAfterViewInit``` and it works! But I also tried to call it in the ```ngOnInit``` in the parent component, ```app.component.ts```, and input into the ```leafLetMapComponent```, but it didn't work. Thank you for your fast reply!